# arctangent implementation in TMS320C55X

Tags: math, assembly, trigonometry, numerical-methods

I'm learning arctangent implementation in TMS320C55x
this is the source code:

```
;* AR0   assigned to _x
;* AR1   assigned to _r
;* T0   assigned to _nx
        PSH     T3
     || BSET    FRCT            ;fractional mode
    SUB #1, T0          ;nx-1
    MOV T0, BRC0        ;repeat nx times
        MOV     #2596 << #16, AC3       ; AC3.Hi = C5
        MOV #-9464 << #16, AC1  ; AC1.Hi = C3
    MOV #32617 << #16, AC2  ; AC2.Hi = C1
*
* Note: loading T3 on the instruction before a multiply that uses it will
* cause a 1-cycle delay.
*
    MPYMR   T3=*AR0+, AC3, AC0      ; (Prime the Pump)
    
     || RPTBLOCAL   loop1-1
            MACR    AC0, T3, AC1, AC0
            MPYR    T3, AC0
          ||MOV *AR0+, T1               ; (for next iteration)
            MACR    AC0, T3, AC2, AC0
            MPYR    T3, AC0
              ||MOV T1, T3
            MOV HI(AC0), *AR1+      ;save result
          ||MPYR    T1, AC3, AC0            ; (for next iteration)
loop1:

        POP     T3
     || BCLR    FRCT            ;return to standard C
    MOV #0, T0          ;return OK value (no possible error)
     || RET
```

where _x is vector of input and _r is output. nx is the number of elements.
The question is about constants that assigns to AC3, AC1, AC2. I guess it is coefficients for polynomial approximation but i don't understand how to calculate them

Comment: this assembly is unknonw to me ... so I can only guess however tan and arctan are usually computed by [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) or [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) ... maybe you should align the code a bit so its more readable and describe non standard mnemonics or even convert the code to equation ... Also what datatype? fixed point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not follow the assembly code, but I could guess where those magic coefficients come from.

The code comments suggest `C1`, `C3`, `C5` are coefficients of a polynomial approximation, and `arctan` is an odd function, so its Taylor expansion around `0` has indeed only odd powers of `x`. Comparing `C1 = 32617` to `1` in the Taylor expansion `y = x - 1/3 x^3 + 1/5 x^5 - 1/7 x^7 + ...`, and given the computational context, this further suggests that the result of the calculation is scaled by `2^15 = 32768`.

It turns out that `y = (32617 x - 9464 x^3 + 2596 x^5) / 32768` is in fact a pretty good approximation of `arctan(x)` over the interval `[-1, 1]`. As shown below (verified in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+abs%28%2832617+x+-+9464+x%5E3+%2B+2596+x%5E5%29+%2F+32768+-+arctan%28x%29%29+from+x++%3D+-1+to+x+%3D+1)) the largest absolute error of the approximation is less than `1/1000`, and is negligible at the endpoints `x = ±1` corresponding to `y = ±π/4`, which is probably desirable in graphics calculations.

[image]

As to how the coefficients were actually derived, a crude polynomial best-fit using just 9 control points [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=32768+*+Fit%5B+%7B+%7B0%2C0%7D%2C+%7B0.15%2Catan%280.15%29%7D%2C+%7B0.25%2Catan%280.25%29%7D%2C+%7B0.4%2Catan%280.4%29%7D%2C+%7B0.5%2Catan%280.5%29%7D%2C+%7B0.6%2Catan%280.6%29%7D%2C+%7B0.75%2Catan%280.75%29%7D%2C+%7B0.85%2Catan%280.85%29%7D%2C+%7B1.0%2Catan%281.0%29%7D+%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+x%5E3%2C+x%5E5%7D%2C+x%5D) a polynomial `y = 32613 x - 9443 x^3 + 2573 x^5` with coefficients already close to the ones used in the posted code. More control points and/or additional conditions to minimize the error at the end points would result in slightly different coefficients, but it's hard to guess how to exactly match the ones in the code without any documentation or clues about the optimization criteria being actually used there.

[image]